# Replicate Word Document Inspector cleanup

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am setting up a Word template in Word 2010 and want to replicate the cleanup of a document that the Word Document Inspector can do.

Optimally I would like to execute that actions that the Document Inspector does from a custom ribbon-button instead.

However when I attempt to record a macro of the Document Inspector doing it's thing, I can only see that it removes document information with the 'ActiveDocument.RemoveDocumentInformation' method.

Does anyone know how to execute the Document Inspector actions from a macro or how to replicate everything that it does?

Comment: I think you first need to identify what it does... Why would you not simply use the `RemoveDocumentInformation` method?

Answer (score 0):

The 'RemoveDocumentInformation' is only a part of the cleanup that is performed via the Document Inspector GUI, which is why further actions are needed to replicate the entire behaviour.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860603.aspx

I discovered that there are several built-in document inspectors that can be accessed via the 'Application.DocumentInspectors' collection. Each of these can be checked or performed with the methods 'Inspect' and 'Fix'.

This allows you to iterate the available document inspectors and perform the cleanup just as it would via the GUI. The collection also gives access to any custom document inspectors installed.

As I needed to identify some particular document inspectors, to only perform some of them, and was not able to do so, I eventually decided to dig further into the individual inspectors' actions and perform them each manually.